# Why mount a folder to a folder in fstab?

Tags: linux, fstab

I'm on an Ubuntu server with fstab like this:

```
/dev/xvds /home/ubuntu/stuff auto  defaults,nofail,nobootwait 0 2
/home/ubuntu/stuff /home/bob/things auto  defaults,nofail,nobootwait,bind 0 2
```

I thought that fstab was for mounting devices to folders. What is the second entry? It seems to mount a folder to a folder, more like a symlink.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you are right.
Fstab record

```
/home/ubuntu/stuff /home/bob/things auto  defaults,nofail,nobootwait,bind 0 2
```

is analogous to the command issued from your shell:

```
mount --bind /home/ubuntu/stuff /home/bob/things
```

It means that you can access **ubuntu/staff** content from **bob/things** folder.

You can read about differences between symbolic link and bind mount here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/557733/ln-s-vs-mount-bind